# OpenERP 7 and WebKit - still printing rml-templates

Tags: webkit, odoo, wkhtmltopdf, rml

Can you tell me what I did wrong when changing over from standard rml reporting to webkit and still standard rml reports are printed? I do not get any error message, no relevant entry in log file. Installed webkit reporting engine, wkhtml2pdf (of course also entered its path to settings), base headers and the webkit report templates relevant to me (up to now, account.invoice and purchase.order are sufficient to me).

Webkit headers I have not customized so far, but at least default header should be available.

Did I forget anything?

Comment: hello, have you changed entries of .py?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but only installing `report_webkit` is not enough - did you also install `account_webkit`?